# How to turn on completion as typing

Tags: webstorm, intellij-inspections

I know we can turn on code completion by shortcut key (`^ SPACE` on MAC), but how to turn on it just by typing like VSCode

For example: with Bootstrap 4 live template when we type `b4` it should be displayed suggestion for the related template.

Comment: WebStorm auto-popups code completion when typing if power save mode is not enabled; but it doesn't happen always - for example, no auto-completion is shown when entering HTML text. It's not clear from your description what you are typing and where, and what live template you are talking about

Comment: As Lena already said: there is no code completion auto popup when entering text in HTML/plain text scope as it is not deterministic as JS/PHP/CSS context is (e.g. how to know for sure if you want to enter a `link` as a plain word or a tag? If you need to enter a bit of plain text ... seeing that many popups for no reason can easily make people mad). If you want to see a list of available Live Templates -- invoke `Code | Insert Live Template` to list all matching entries.